# Command not returning expected output

Tags: python, discord.py

I have made a changeprefix command. I noticed it wasn't returning the output i want it to and not changing the prefix with no errors in the console.
I did some debugging with the print method and found out the code stops at this line.

```py
prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix
```

The whole code is.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import logging
import json

logging.basicConfig(filename='log.log', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

class changeprefix(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_guild_permissions(administrator = True)
    async def changeprefix(ctx, prefix):
        print("Yo!")
        with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
            prefixes = json.load(f)
        
            prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix

        with open("prefixes.json","w") as f:
            json.dump(prefixes,f)
        
        await ctx.send(f"The prefix has been changed to {prefix}")


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(changeprefix(bot))
```

If anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: I am also getting that malfunction when trying to parse with json.

Comment: have you tried storing `str(ctx.guild.id)` into a variable and call it here? `prefixes[variable_name] = prefix`

Comment: try de-indenting that line by one tab and see what happens, this way, you open the file, read the file, close the file, change the prefix, then open the file again, then write the change to the file, then close the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all of the help with this.
It was a very stupid idiot mistake that i made. Because i am using a cog my command must start with self, ctx but it started with ctx.

The new updated code is

```py
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_guild_permissions(administrator = True)
    async def changeprefix(self, ctx, prefix : str):
        print("Yo!")
        with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
            prefixes = json.load(f)
        
        string = str(ctx.guild.id)
        prefixes[string] = prefix

        with open("prefixes.json","w") as f:
            json.dump(prefixes,f)
        
        await ctx.send(f"The prefix has been changed to {prefix}")
```